# udev interface for python3?

Tags: python-3.x, gobject-introspection, libudev

Is there any example on how to capture `udev` events in Python3? I can't get events working at all in .237 (or 1.0?). And couldn't get *any* examples of GUdev with Introspection.

I'm not sure where the problem lies. I found an example `test.py` but there, parameters are given when instantiating `Client` like in `client = GUdev.Client(['block'])`. Those parameters are not accepted in the actual version (`TypeError: GObject.__init__() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)`).

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('GUdev', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GUdev, GLib

def on_uevent(client, action, device):
    print(action)

client = GUdev.Client()
client.connect('uevent', on_uevent)

GLib.MainLoop().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, well. Seems the G(NU|nome|object)-Introspection changed a few things in its workings.

```
...
client = GUdev.Client.new(['block'])
client.connect('uevent', on_uevent)
...
```

works fine (Note the addition of `.new`). I don't know why the old syntax (see above) doesn't throw any errors...

BTW, `GUdev.Client.new(['block'])` accepts multiple values in the list.